# Chrome extension's content scripts doesn't affect a particular website

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extension that uses a content script to inject a particular word into the web page. It works in a certain website x but doesn't work in y.

Manifest

```
 {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "word",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "chat"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Background.js

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    });
```

Inject.js

```
// this is the code which will be injected into a given page...
(function() {
// just place a div at top right
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.position = 'fixed';
div.style.top = 600;
div.style.right = 700;
div.textContent = 'Hello!';
document.body.appendChild(div);
})();
```

This code works on adding the word in the website: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.js

Doesn't work in web.whatsapp.com among other common websites.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for any errors? Maybe the site blocks the content script.

Comment: Did you try adding matches" : ["*://*/*"] ?

Comment: @elegant-user No, that didn't work :(

Comment: Show your code. Please otherwise we just can't help you.

Comment: Sure, do you need the manifest or the scripts?

Comment: Provide  both in your question.

Comment: @elegant-user Edited.

Comment: I checked your code on web.whatsapp.com and it actually works well.

Comment: @Ansh - added my answer with working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added `"*://*/*",` into your manifest to make working.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "word",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "chat"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    });
```

inject.js

```
(function() {
    console.log("Inject successfully.");
    // just place a div at top right
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = 600;
    div.style.right = 700;
    div.style.zIndex = 9999;
    div.textContent = 'Hello!';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
})();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem on https://www.smashingmagazine.com/, my content script doesn't load on any pages I've tried there. I tried adding the permission "*://*/*" as recommended and "<all_urls>", no difference, and no other sites I've run into require either. I'm using an extremely permissive manifest, "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]. Don't get it. Any thoughts are most welcome.